# Cannot install golint package: wrong import path

Tags: docker, go, golint

I have a project that uses golint and installs it inside the docker container. It have been working ok for months (and have been built multiple times), but today when I build the container again I get the following error:
go get -u github.com/golang/lint/golint

```
package github.com/golang/lint/golint: 
code in directory /a-go-path/golang/lint/golint expects import "golang.org/x/lint/golint"
```

I can replicate the issue locally on my computer by typing go get github.com/golang/lint/golint. I have deleted all the packages related to golint in the go path (source and bin folders), still when I try to install it again I get the former error. 
I am using go 1.11.0
Any recommendations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are [supposed](https://github.com/golang/lint#installation) to use `go get -u golang.org/x/lint/golint` to install `golint`. Note that this is exactly the URL in the error message.

You'll need to modify the image you use to build the container to use this URL.

It started to happen yesterday due to [this](https://github.com/golang/lint/commit/9a272034dedb2a3ed05231d5604ce17fb40f0e58) commit (they added `golang.org/x/lint/golint` as the import path). See [this](https://github.com/golang/lint/issues/415) issue for more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
go get -u golang.org/x/lint/golint
```

it has been updated to this